# tensorflow: gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-msse4.2'

Tags: gcc, tensorflow, compilation

I was lead to the [official tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) to install it from source, in order to resolve warning such as `The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations`, it seems like they've left out the most important part regarding how the optimization flags are to be specified during configuration (`./configure`).

Feeding them incorrectly has lead to the following errors resulted in errors like these when building with invalid configurations(`bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`):

```
...
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-mavx'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-mavx2'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-mfma'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-msse4.1'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-msse4.2'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-mavx'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-mavx2'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-mfma'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-msse4.1'
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--copt=-msse4.2'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

What is the right way to specify the optimization flags?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem putting the following in my "./configure":

```
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 
--copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-mfpmath=both --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2
```

As linked by reubenjohn , in the gcc doc, '-march=whatever' is at the same level as say '-msse4.1', thus, '--copt=' has to be removed as these options are in fact directly fed to gcc.

Solved by putting instead:

```
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 
-mavx -mavx2 -mfma -mfpmath=both -msse4.1 -msse4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you may have missed out the part where [the guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) specifies:

> We recommend accepting the default (-march=native), which will optimize the generated code for your local machine's CPU type. However, if you are building TensorFlow on one CPU type but will run TensorFlow on a different CPU type, then consider specifying a more specific optimization flag as described in the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html).

And in the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html), you will find listings such as:

> -mmmx
>   -mno-mmx
>   -msse
>   -mno-sse
>   -msse2
>   -mno-sse2
>   -msse3
>   -mno-sse3
>   -mssse3
>   -mno-ssse3
>   -msse4.1
>   -mno-sse4.1
>   -msse4.2
>   -mno-sse4.2
>   -msse4
>   -mno-sse4
>   -mavx
>   -mno-avx
>   -maes
>   -mno-aes
>   -mpclmul
>   -mno-pclmul
>   -msse4a
>   -mno-sse4a
>   -mfma4
>   -mno-fma4
>   -mxop
>   -mno-xop
>   -mlwp
>   -mno-lwp
>   -m3dnow
>   -mno-3dnow
>   -mpopcnt
>   -mno-popcnt
>   -mabm
>   -mno-abm